# Adjust c3 axis labels with css

Tags: css, r, c3.js

I am using R's c3 package which is a wrapper for the C3 javascript charting library by Masayuki Tanaka.

My c3 chart below cuts off the last date on the x-axis.

[image]

Using Chrome Inspector I can manually adjust the `text-anchor: middle` to `text-anchor: end`

[image]

and that seems to work.

[image]

However, I do not understand how to do this with css.

Here's my R Script and related css though I don't think that R is relevant to the issue here.

R Script

```
library(shiny)
library(c3)

data <- data.frame(a = abs(rnorm(20) * 10),
                   b = abs(rnorm(20) * 10),
                   date = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 20))


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  includeCSS("c3.css"),
  
  c3Output("chart",  height = "100%")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$chart <- renderC3({
    data %>%
      c3(x = 'date') %>%
      tickAxis('x', count = 5, format = '%Y-%m-%d') 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

css

```
.c3-line {
  stroke-width: 4px !important; 
}

.c3-axis-x-label {
    text-anchor: end; 
}
```

Comment: If  you paste a working example, I might be able to help you out.

Comment: I included my R script and related css file. So when you say, "Paste a working example", you must mean something else. Please clarify if you can.

Comment: You can use your code to create a real working example in websites like jsfiddle, codepen, etc

Comment: I think the disconnect we are having is that I generate the c3 chart using R and I need to modify it using css.

Comment: I have already provided an answer using CSS.

Comment: I replaced my .c3-axis-x-label with your suggestion. There was no change.

Comment: To change the TICK position, you need to alter the `.c3-axis-x` class and NOT the `.c3-axis-x-label` class. In fact copy/paste the code on my answer and see if anything happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227294/discussion-between-ixodid-and-scooterlord).

Comment: Sorry was not available at that time

Comment: @scooterlord were you able to determine the selector, ".c3-axis-x g.tick:nth-last-child(3) text " just by using Chrome Inspector (or equivalent) and viewing the code under, "Elements"?

Comment: I used my own implementation of a chart rendered using C3. Judging by the image of your inspector this might work out of the box. We are talking about changing the value of the date tick value, right?

Comment: Your solution works well on a large screen. However, on my iphone 8 the nudge left has to be greater. Is that common? My  earlier question had to do with how you determined the selector, ".c3-axis-x g.tick:nth-last-child(3) text ". From Chrome Inspector it was not at all obvious to me.

Comment: You can replace the percentage with an absolute value that suits you, for example ‘-10px’! Glad it worked! Also please reply to the answer so that other users an keep track of the conversation and have the right context

Answer (score 1):

You haven't pasted any actual code, but it's highly likely that the code below will help:

```
.c3-axis-x g.tick:nth-last-child(3) text {
  transform:translateX(-5%);
}
```

You need to target the text correctly and adjust value to your needs.

Edit: Actually it's not `:last-child` - adjusted, based on some actual code. In essence you need to target your selector properly and apply the `transform` property.

Edit2: So it was actually the `.c3-axis-x` group that includes the tick texts. Code updated (yet again)

Comment: Your solution worked. Also replacing percentage with an absolute value is preferred since it also works on iPhone. Still a mystery to me how you arrived at this selector, ".c3-axis-x g.tick:nth-last-child(3) text ".

Comment: Thanks for accepting this as the correct reply. You start by investigating the hierarchy on your inspector. Check the screenshot you uploaded for example. The parent container you want to use to target the tick label is `c3-axis c3-axis-x`... In this case we prefer the `c3-axis-c` because the `c3-axis` class might also be used for the Y axis as well. Then you need to target a specific group `g` with the `tick` class that holds the last tick label you want changed - the date. Now, C3.js as a library renders all charts in a specific manner, so I rendered a chart here and noticed that...

Comment: (cont)...the group that holds the last tick label, is the 3rd element counting backwards from the end (thus the `:nth-last-child(3)`). Lastly, the `text` element is the one that holds the actual tick text, so it's the one you want changed, because if you notice the `tick` group also holds the tick line. Does all this make more sense to you now? If you are interested to learn more, I would suggest searching for CSS specificity and CSS selectors.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed explanation and definitely need to learn more about CSS specificity and CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that popps to my head immediately:

With your css you are only targeting the 'date' element.
You other 'text' element doesnt have a class, therefore the css for '.c3-axis-x-label' will only target the first text element.

Try adding 'c3-axis-x-label' class also to your other 'text' element.

Another thing:

The 'text' tag that you want to adjust has its styles written in the tag
[image: style="..."]

When you set styles like this it will always override the applied CSS.

One solution i can think of, is to add !important in your CSS to override the style. I do not recommend using !important, but if its too difficult to actually change the css directly then this might be a solution.

If you can add a class to the other text element the try applying styles to 'text' in your css:

```
g > text {
   text-anchor: end; 
}
```

Let me know if any of that helped. Otherwise some code would come in handy to help you out